# Repeat a specific text x number of times in one column taken from another column of Random text strings

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I have some Text Values in sheet 1, A4:A400 and for each value in Column A there are 10 codes in non-consecutive cells in Row 1.
I want a formula in "sheet 2" to put each text value 10 times in column A with the code in column B and then repeat the same with a new text value with the same 10 cods.
LIke:

```
1
2   . . . . . . 5310    5200        3310    3456            3600
3   PK64                                
4   PK967                               
5   PK106                               
6   PK369                               
7   PK250                               
8   PK222
```

It should look like this

```
1   A       B                           
2   PK64    5310                            
3   PK64    5200                            
4   PK64    3310                            
5   PK64    3456                            
6   PK64    3600                            
7   PK967   5310                            
8   PK967   5200                            
9   PK967   3310                            
10  PK967   3456                            
11  PK967   3600
```

I used `=INT((ROW()-1)/3)+1` but it increments and repeats the number only.

I also used `=REPT(B1,ROW()-1/5)` but it repeats the text in the same cell with increased number of times as the row number increments.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all codes are numeric and with no repetitions you can do this:

With PK's starting at A4

write in J4 the first PK (in your example "PK64")

In K4 write the formula:

```
=MIN(2:2)
```

Now write in J5 and K5 the formulas:

```
=IF(K5=MIN($2:$2);INDEX(A:A;MATCH(J4;A:A;0)+1);J4)

=IF(K4=MAX($2:$2);MIN($2:$2);SMALL($2:$2;RANK(K4;$2:$2;1)+1))
```

Copy, at the same time, both formulas down and you get the pretended result

Depending on your regional settings you may need to replace ";" by ","

Comment: Thanks alot, CRondao! It just worked perfectly though takes time to master it.